# What Time Is This Returning

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Deep in the sauce here. I haven't worked with time to much so I'm a little confused here.  I know there is FILETIME and SYSTEMTIME. What I am trying to get at this point (because it might change) are file that are less than a 20 seconds old. This returning the files and their size and something in seconds, What I'd like to know is where it is filtering by time if it is, and how can I adjust it to suit my needs. Thank you.

```
using namespace std;
typedef vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> tFoundFilesVector;
std::wstring LastWriteTime;  
int getFileList(wstring filespec, tFoundFilesVector &foundFiles)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    HANDLE h;
    int validResult=true;

    int numFoundFiles = 0;
    h = FindFirstFile(filespec.c_str(), &findData);

    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    while (validResult)
    {
        numFoundFiles++;
        foundFiles.push_back(findData);
        validResult = FindNextFile(h, &findData);
    }
    return numFoundFiles;
}

void showFileAge(tFoundFilesVector &fileList)
{
    unsigned _int64 fileTime, curTime, age;
    tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter;
    FILETIME ftNow;
    //__int64 nFileSize;
          //LARGE_INTEGER li;    
    //li.LowPart = ftNow.dwLowDateTime;
    //li.HighPart = ftNow.dwHighDateTime;

    CoFileTimeNow(&ftNow);
          curTime = ((_int64) ftNow.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ftNow.dwLowDateTime;

          for (iter=fileList.begin(); iter<fileList.end(); iter++)
    {
        fileTime = ((_int64)iter->ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime << 32) + iter->ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime;

        age = curTime - fileTime;

        cout << "FILE: '" << iter->cFileName << "', AGE: " << (_int64)age/10000000UL << "  seconds" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string fileSpec = "*.*";
    tFoundFilesVector foundFiles;
    tFoundFilesVector::iterator iter;

    int foundCount = 0;

    getFileList(L"c:\\Mapper\\*.txt", foundFiles);
    getFileList(L"c:\\Mapper\\*.jpg", foundFiles);

    foundCount = foundFiles.size();
    if (foundCount)
    {
        cout << "Found "<<foundCount<<" matching files.\n";
        showFileAge(foundFiles);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What numbers do you get for a file that was created (or last modified) at a known time? You can then relate the two.

Comment: A file 49 minutes old...returns 2965 seconds when the code is run. Doesn't sound right??? Or is this filetime 2965 and I am completely off base?

Comment: well 2965/60 is approximately 49.5 so yes it does sound about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you've done to try to debug this but your code doesn't work at all.  The reason is you're passing getFileList() a wstring but then passing that to the ANSI version of FindFirstFile().  Unless you #define UNICODE or use the appropriate compiler option, all system calls will expect char *, not UNICODE.

The easiest fix is to simply change the declaration of getFileList() to this:

```
int getFileList(const char * filespec, tFoundFilesVector &foundFiles)
```

Change the call to FindFirstFile() to this:

```
h = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR)filespec, &findData);
```

And then change the calls to it to this:

```
getFileList("c:\\Mapper\\*.txt", foundFiles);
getFileList("c:\\Mapper\\*.jpg", foundFiles);
```

Your other option is to switch all char strings to wide chars, but either way you need to be consistent throughout.  Once you do that the program works as expected.

As for your final question, your program is not filtering by time at all.

Comment: hmmmm, now I am completely confused....when I run the code pre suggestions. I get this.                                       Found 1 matching files.
FILE: '006547BC', AGE: 53739  seconds
Press any key to continue . . .                                                       And when I change things. I get Press any key.

Comment: I have no idea why it found any file but you're passing the FindFirstFile function bad data.  What files are in the c:\Mapper folder with *.txt or *.jpg extensions?

Comment: Then that's your problem.  You need to decide if you're using ANSI or UNICODE and be consistent throughout.  Make my suggested changes, remove the UNICODE, and it will work.

Comment: OK, Being new to this. What would you say is better. UNICODE or ANSI. I;m grabbing size and time.  In the meantime I will switch to Ansi and try your suggestions. Thank you. VS 2010. I have a choice of multibyte and not set. Which one?

Comment: OUTPUT   Found 2 matching files.
FILE: '2.txt', AGE: 54816  seconds
FILE: 'ONEWAY.txt', AGE: 362  seconds
Press any key to continue . . . Not Set

Comment: Set it to multibyte and get it working with my suggestions.  Once you've done that, if you think your application will ever need to be used worldwide, then converting it to UNICODE would be advisable.  It should be a fairly simple change, but get it working in ANSI first.

Comment: All suggestions followed. I have this.  Found 2 matching files.
FILE: '2.txt', AGE: 55677  seconds
FILE: 'ONEWAY.txt', AGE: 1224  seconds
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3972/discussion-between-me-dia-and-carey-gregory)

Comment: Is the response I am getting in filetime or system time? Thank you.

Comment: Carey, all recent versions of Visual Studio use Unicode by default for all new projects.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but you might want to read about [file system tunneling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172190).

It may prevent you from what you're trying to do in some situations.

Comment: Wow! That is a very good thing to know! I appreciate the input!